# How / where can I include a library?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

how can I include a custom library in Drupal ?

For example I need to insert this statement somewhere, to use the dompdf library:

```
require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");
```

Once the this file is included, i can trigger custom php code from my drupal back-end custom actions.

thanks

Comment: The right function to call, when including files containing PHP code is `module_load_include()`. `require_once()` would look for a file with the name passed as argument in the current directory, which is the directory where Drupal is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 Places to do it would be

- In a module's `.module` file, if you always want it included
- Wrapped in a function that you can call, if you manually want to include it.

Answer (score 4):

You want to include it, in order to use it, not?
If so, just include it at the place where you are going to use it. 
E.g. in your own `dompdf.module`.

. That module would then distribute the dompdf funcitonality trough your Drupal site.

Another, common route is to place the include in `/sites/all/libraries/`
and then to include it from your `dompdf.module`. 
libraries in `/sites/all/libraries/` are often libraries that will be used in more then only your module: probably in your theme too, or in other modules too.

Comment: well, if I include it at the place where I'm going to use it, I'm going to invoke this line all the time i invoke the function. Is that ok ? I mean including it multiple times ? (This is more php question)

Comment: h, yes. to include files in Drupal, you have several options depending on the version. Drupal6?

Comment: yes drupal6. Anyway now it works. If I can keep the require statement inside my PHP snippet, it is fine for me

Comment: beware: those snippets have many downsides. But that is a whole different post.